# Bootstrap 4 Hamburger Menu Not Showing Navbar

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

This is for my mobile sized site.  When I click the hamburger menu, the Navbar does not appear.  My `data-target` matches the `nav id` so I'm not sure why it isn't working.

```
<section id="nav">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md py-2">
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="./img/logo.png" class="img-fluid mw-121 height: auto" alt="Logo">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarLinks"><span
                    class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarLinks">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="flavors.html">Flavors</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="details.html">What's Included</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="reserve.html">Reserve Today</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

Comment: I don't think this html is the problem,  maybe your css is.Please show your css related to this section.

Comment: Isn't ul navbar-nav and also is Bootstrap and js included? What does your console shows on devtools?

Comment: its working, try to add required files like bootstrap css and js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used your code to replicate the problem but it's working fine. Check my code below you might be missing one of the dependencies.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="nav">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md py-2">
            <a href="index.html">
                <p>Test Image here</p>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarLinks"><span
                    class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarLinks">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="flavors.html">Flavors</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="details.html">What's Included</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="reserve.html">Reserve Today</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, all!  I was missing the js dependency.

Comment: @shanbark it’s my pleasure to help you