# Bootstrap 5.0.2 hamburger menu not working

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap 5.0.2](http://%3Clink%20href=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20integrity=%22sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%3E) version Here I am trying for hamburger menu.

Here is my code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sample</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" style="margin-right:5px !important;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse top_nav" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto ">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                <hr class="hr_nav">
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link">Support</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-right" style="display:flex;">
            <li>
                <button class="btn top_login">
                    Login
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="btn sign_btn">
                    SignUp
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

What I am doing wrong here why hamburger menu not working.

When I search [STO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60663809/bootstrap-4-hamburger-menu-not-showing-navbar) I got the reply that I need to add Jquery.

But others saying **Bootstrap 5 is designed to be used without jQuery, but it's still possible to use our components with jQuery. If Bootstrap detects jQuery in the window object it'll add all of our components in jQuery's plugin system; this means you'll be able to do $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').**

Here if you see I had the reference image

[image]

I have added the code [here](https://liveweave.com/GRQcA6)

I am not getting the menu when i click the hamburger

Comment: @blurfus thanks for posting but I am looking for solution

Comment: The other question has been answered already.  is there something else in particular that is not answered there?

Comment: Please don't minus vote

Comment: @blurfus actually not helped me I am struggling here still

Comment: That's hardly a good description of what the issue is.  Have you tried the suggestions in the dupe question and they didn't work for you?  What did you do and what errors did you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237151/discussion-between-mr-m-and-blurfus).

Comment: As I mentioned in the chat, please include an [mcve] of the issue you are having... It is very hard to debug an image

Comment: @blurfus I have added the code in online tool (Liveweaver) please check

Comment: You are naming the attributes incorrectly, see my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your data attributes are incorrect.  Instead of naming them `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target` you named them without the `-bs` and they would not work.

See the code below and running example:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" style="margin-right:5px !important;" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sample</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" style="margin-right:5px !important;" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse top_nav" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto ">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          <hr class="hr_nav">
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-right" style="display:flex;">
        <li>
          <button class="btn top_login">
                    Login
                </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="btn sign_btn">
                    SignUp
                </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Worked for me with BS 5.2.1

Comment: I asked chatGPT for solutions to this, no joy. This little change saved me from hair pulling frustration. StackOverflow!